# Reuse data from API in another component | REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to fetch some data from an API and then use it everywhere, even outside the component. To be more specific, I managed to fetch some data through an API and are able to do some manipulation about it in the component where I did the call to fetch, but how can I still get access to those fetched data when I am in another component?

In `Tables.js` I did the call to fetch from API and created a table for it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
const Tables = () => {
    const [users, setUser] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(TEST_URL)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
           setUser(data);
            console.log(data)
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>ADDRESS</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {users}.map((m) => (
                        <tr key={m.id}>
                            <td>{m.name}</td>
                            <td>{m.address}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>

        
    );
}

export default Tables
```

And the data in the API looks like this:

```
[
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "decster",
 "address": "space",
 "phone": "123"
}
]
```

Now I have another component called `TableDetails.js`, I would like to use the data from the API without re-fetching it, and create a table rendering a different part of that data, for example: displaying "name" and "phone" from the JSON data this time. How should I do it?

```
import Tables from "./Tables.js";

function TableDetails() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2> 
                <Tables Tables {users} = {columns}>
            </h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TableDetails
```

Another small issue I have is that after fetching the data in `Tables.js`, it repeatedly print the data in the console log twice? I am very nice to REACT and also JS, so any tips would be very helpful! Thanks

Comment: Pass it as props: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the `console.log` runs twice can be because of using the `React.StrictMode` wrapper in the root of the project **(index.js)**.

If you want the **API** to run somewhere and its data can be accessed in other components, you need a state manager like [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)
or in the simpler form, you can use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Here I write a solution for your problem using `useContext`.

Create a context called `DataContext` and in the `App` component, wrap all the content around it.*(I am using jsonplaceholder fake data here)*

```
export const DataContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const callApi = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setData(json));
  }
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{data, callApi}}>
      <C1 />
      <C2 />
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Now `callApi` function and `data` value are accessible inside each child component.
`C1` calls getPosts API using `callApi` from context.

```
export default function C1() {
    const { callApi } = useContext(DataContext);
    useEffect(() => {
        callApi();
    }, [])
    return (
        <>This is C1 component. It calls the API.</>
    )
}
```

`C2` can get API result from `data` value of the context.

```
export default function C2() {
    const { data } = useContext(DataContext);
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                This is C2 it gets API data from DataContext which has been called by C1
            </div>
            {
                data && data.map((post,index) => 
                    <p key={index}> { JSON.stringify(post) } </p>
                )
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think I will go for another solution other than useContext, but what you mentioned about the StrictMode solved my issue. I will accept this answer.